# Htaccess Redirect Rule for 0-9 .html and Query String

Tags: 301-redirect

I am new here and writing my question. Seeking help to resolve a redirection issue.

I want to redirect the following similar URL structure to the given example;

URL: `https://example.com/jobs/0020840812.html?addto_wish`

Redirect to:

URL: `https://example.com/jobs/`

or redirect to:

URL: `https://example.com/`

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! [Server Fault is a site for information technology professionals](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) -- as such we have certain professional expectations when people ask a question here, and one of those expectations is that your question shows you did some **research**, found and **read the vendor documentation** and/or **tried a solution** before asking the internet for help. You're not expected to solve everything yourself, but then at least you can [write a great question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) that we can help you answer.